# Fly To Location in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, pan, mapbox-gl

Is it possible to 'fly to location' in Leaflet in the same way as [this Mapbox GL](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/flyto-options/) example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`map.flyTo()` is available in Leaflet 1.0.

However the parameters are different from those in the example. See
http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-flyto

`flyTo(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom?, <Zoom/pan options> options?)`

Example:

`flyTo([13.87992, 45.9791], 12)`

Comment: Have you seen any examples of its use? Or any detailed documentation on the parameters?

Comment: Leaflet implementation is much lighter than MapBox obviously: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/

Comment: Perfect, yes as you say it is a lot lighter but it does the job, cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to make the map 'render' as the animation is happening, for example, for a marker.cluster layer to expand as the map animates?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, flyTo() function in Leaflet 1.0 (in Beta at the moment). 
Demo http://regionbound.com/leaflet-fly-demo

Comment: flyTo() is nice, but the effect seems to be kind of lost when you don't get tiles reloading faster enough, like in regionbound demo. Has anyone made any progress with this? Does it work better with vector tiles? Can we preload tiles?