# leaflet How to bounce map

Tags: leaflet

I would like to do button like **Fly to Bern** button in the below link.

Is it possible to do ?

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/animation.html

```
var flyToBern = document.getElementById('fly-to-bern');
flyToBern.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var duration = 2000;
  var start = +new Date();
  var pan = ol.animation.pan({
    duration: duration,
    source: /** @type {ol.Coordinate} */ (view.getCenter()),
    start: start
  });
  var bounce = ol.animation.bounce({
    duration: duration,
    resolution: 4 * view.getResolution(),
    start: start
  });
  map.beforeRender(pan, bounce);
  view.setCenter(bern);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with Leaflet 1.0, but with a more simple API (you specify only target latlng and duration of the "flyTo" animation).

See [Leaflet Fly To Location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168687/leaflet-fly-to-location) post for details.

However it does not do anything if you are already on the target position I think.

Comment: but I cannot just use flyTo.js. It will bring up a error. Unless I use v1.0.0-beta.2 version of leaflet.  Do you have any example by using leaflet-0.7.2 version.

Comment: Nope sorry, you need Leaflet 1.0 unfortunately. Or import the code yourself and debug whatever needs to.